# Turn ground upside down

Tags: circuitikz

How can i turn the ground upside down , when i do

```
\draw (0,0) to (0,1) node[ground]{}
```

it shows me something like this
[image: j]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always post a MWE (minimal working example).

Answer (score 5):

As with most [`TikZ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) nodes, the `rotate` key is accepted here and so `rotate=180` seems to do the job here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[ground,rotate=180]{}; 
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Electrical ground rotated]